# convert json object to string boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

I am new to stackoverflow sorry if i do any  error  please do  correct  me if  i am wrong. I did a lot  of  research regarding json parser and xml parser  in boost .The thing i want to do is ,suppose  i have a json as shown below

```
      {
           "topology_1":{
           "clnt_id":"aldgdsgsd",
           "sensors":{
                       "num_sensors":"6",
                        "sensor_1":{
                                     "time_interval":"5#15",
                                     "min_bound":"",
                                     "max_bound":"54",
                                     "anomaly":"2%",
                                     "anomaly_window":"70",
                                     "jump":"10",
                                     "topic":"sense/thubrahali/temp",
                                      "qos":"1"
                                   }
                     }
         }
     }
```

i want to convert the the value of 'topology'  fetched from boost  jsonparser  to string  in order store it somewhere in a container for later use.Now  i can't really  directly  fetch the value via  theboost  library as it treats it as a json object.How should i convert this value to string.

Comment: "I did a lot of research regarding json parser and xml parser in boost" - that's interesting, because Boost has no JSON library, nor an XML library.

Comment: yes  i was sort  using  thatcrack  facilityof  parsing  json and xml so sortof since  i heard  its  the  most  used  library in c++ i went on  for this for parsing  json and xml.I also read its documentation and tried  some workarounds but iwas nowhere  near finding the solution since  i am new to using the boost library :(

Comment: @sehe: I thought Property Tree supported JSON.

Comment: @ChristianHackl it supports Property Trees. As such, it can serialize into subsets of a few familiar text formats, not dissimilar to JSON or XML. But the feature set is so limited it keeps getting people in trouble. --> https://twitter.com/search?q=propertytree%20from%3Asehetw&src=typd

Comment: yes  actually  you are  right it doesnt really  offer the real purpose  of  json but  it is sort of a  workaround  of parsing  json

Comment: @sense_kusbhatt for a quick and dirty, you are /probably/ going to be ok. I'd not allow it in production code that should handle JSON from uncontrolled sources

Comment: actually i am running  it in a test  bench environment  which would test my  original application whether  it is resistant to every possible scenarios

Comment: have a look at the library json_spirit. It is a json parser written entirely using the boost.spirit parsing library.

Comment: actually  its  been  a long  journey applying  the  boost parser  can i integrate  it  easily with  json_spirit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual caveat applies, boost doesn't have a JSON library. If you stay within the subset afforded by Boost Property Tree, you could:

```
std::string as_json_string(ptree const& pt) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    write_json(oss, pt);
    return oss.str();
}
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ae0bc44202b5788)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

std::string as_json_string(ptree const& pt) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    write_json(oss, pt);
    return oss.str();
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"({
        "topology_1": {
            "clnt_id": "aldgdsgsd",
            "sensors": {
                "num_sensors": "6",
                "sensor_1": {
                    "time_interval": "5#15",
                    "min_bound": "",
                    "max_bound": "54",
                    "anomaly": "2%",
                    "anomaly_window": "70",
                    "jump": "10",
                    "topic": "sense/thubrahali/temp",
                    "qos": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    })");

    ptree document;
    read_json(iss, document);

    // and back to string
    std::string topology_1 = as_json_string(document.get_child("topology_1"));

    std::cout << topology_1;
}
```

Prints

```
{
    "clnt_id": "aldgdsgsd",
    "sensors": {
        "num_sensors": "6",
        "sensor_1": {
            "time_interval": "5#15",
            "min_bound": "",
            "max_bound": "54",
            "anomaly": "2%",
            "anomaly_window": "70",
            "jump": "10",
            "topic": "sense\/thubrahali\/temp",
            "qos": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks  for the answer :)  but  how  do i remove'\' from the answer of': "sense\/thubrahali\/temp"  is  it  due  to the osstrream

Comment: What is the question? You wanted the value of topology as a JSON string. Next time consider asking the question (saying what you tried and what you expect instead of what you got).

Comment: i tried getting its  internal values and then i concatenated the key value pair  but the algorithm was too long  and tedious and the code was not  flexible too

Comment: thanx  for this answer i was in dire need of this flexible code

Comment: sorry if i was sort of unclear about myintention i truely apologise for this

Comment: @sense_kusbhatt perhaps you just want `std::cout << document.get("topology_1.sensors.sensor_1.topic", "");`

Comment: no actually  i want  the whole json as  a whole  sorry  if  i confused  u but actually it was better if  i got the orginial string  as it is but  thanx  this code is a lot better and flexible :)